# Would the Imperium of Man fall if the Emperor finally died?

Tags: warhammer-40k

How long would Humans last without their golden child? Would they be able to recover from such a death.

Comment: That does sound a lot like an opinion-based question

Comment: Seven. Seven fast.

Comment: I suggest changing to "What are the possible scenarios for the Empire if Emperor would die", which is answerable in-universe

Comment: Changed and requested we reopen it. Thank you :)

Comment: @JamieHutber still too broad to be answered. The Emperor is Godlike. so if he died the consequences could be everything and anything or nothing at all. We dont know.

Comment: Updated again @Cherubel Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to give you an actual time because there is no way to know.  It's been a long time since I looked at the source material, but there are at least two broad answers: Very quickly, and Not at all.

The main canon would suggest that without the Emperor, the astropaths would quickly get whacked by daemons and navigators lose their protection/beacon.  Total shutdown of all interstellar comms and travel would make the job of guarding humanity on the physical front nigh impossible. Further, you'd no longer be transporting all the minor packers to Earth do feed the god-corpse, which would exponentially increase the number of potential possession vectors.  It might take a while for the last vestiges of humanity to get eaten by , but it wouldn't be long on the galactic timetable.

I do recall some stories in the older books (I want to say Realms of Chaos, the originals), that suggested that keeping the Emperor trapped on the Golden Throne was actually preventing him from being reborn better, harder, faster, stronger, and so it would be better to unplug him.  I don't have a reference for that as my RoC books were lost years ago.

Comment: I recall some more recent sources - possibly some of the Daemonhunters stuff, that implies that the death of the emperor would result in another "god" being born into the immaterium of Chaos - one with Humanity in it's best interests

Comment: one of the inquisitorbooks also implied that it could be better to unplug him as he is unstable (insane). Also humanity already had this situation once (before the great crusade).....but there were no chaos marines who would be ready to take action when that happens

Comment: The Emperor is a perpetual like Grammaticus and Vulcan, among others. It is the goal of the Thorian faction of the Inquisitoin to reincarnate the Emperor in a different body. They are opposed by at least 1 other Inquisition faction. http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Thorians

Comment: @Thomas: but before the Crusade, there were no loyalist Space Marines to oppose the Chaotic ones.

Comment: Do you have any source for the fact that the Astronomican protects navigators? My understanding was that it acted as a lighthouse, and the navigator were protected by Gellar fields.

Comment: @Taladris you are correct that the geller field is the primary means of protection. it protects the entire ship. The Astronomicon is a beacon that helps them navigate. Without it navigators wouldn't be able to make long jumps through the warp. Traffic though the empire would crawl to a standstill almost.

Comment: @taladris before the crusade (and Horus) there were also no chaotic space marines ;)

Comment: @Thomas: I know. This is exactly what you said in your previous comment, no?

Comment: @Taladris thanks for clarifying. I was grouping together concepts but when I said "protection" I was thinking more about protection from getting lost in space, the possession part wasn't something if thought of.